# Improve code for increasing font size in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a functionality to increase/decrease font size of the page. The font size of the navbar cannot increase beyond 19px and that of the rest of the content cannot go beyond 50px ; and in case of decrement- the font size of navbar cannot decrease below the current size and that of the rest cannot go below 20px.
I have only written the code for the page content(which is working). I need help with completing it for the navbar and improving the code.

Below is the HTML,CSS & JS code -

```js
function inc() {

  var el = document.getElementById('test');
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
  var fontSize = parseFloat(style);
  console.log("SIZE", fontSize)
  if (fontSize <= 50) {
    el.style.fontSize = (fontSize + 2) + 'px';
    console.log("incSize", el.style.fontSize)
  }

}

function dec() {
  var el = document.getElementById('test');
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
  var fontSize = parseFloat(style);
  console.log("SIZE", fontSize)

  if (fontSize >= 20) {
    el.style.fontSize = (fontSize - 2) + 'px';
    console.log("decSize", el.style.fontSize)
  }

}
```

```css
/* Basic styling */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background: #001a33;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: white;
  font-size: 12.8px;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #91d5f3;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.submenu {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.submenu-select {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg py-0 " id="header-bar">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-dark navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="first">ITEM1<span
                                class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link " href="#">ITEM0</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link px-3" href="#">ITEM2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link " href="#">ITEM3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link px-3 " href="#">ITEM4</a>
        </li>
        <label for="submenu" class="submenu px-2">Submenu:</label>
        <select name="submenu" id="submenu" class="submenu-select">
          <option value="Option1">option1</option>
          <option value="Option2">option2</option>
        </select>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<button onclick="inc()">INCREASE</button>
<button onclick="dec()">DECREASE</button>

<h1 id="test">FONT CHANGE</h1>
```

Comment: Just like @mplungjan said you should be getting errors like "ReferenceError: increase is not defined" or "ReferenceError: decrease is not defined" in your console while debugging this.

Comment: I pasted the code in a hurry. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: So change   var el = document.getElementById('test'); to include more elements

Comment: @mplungjan I forgot to change the name of the function. My bad. The logic works fine otherwise. I needed help with the rest.

Comment: You will not find many ppl who even HAVE IE8 installed to help you make this compatible with that ancient un-supported browser

Comment: Remove `font-size: 12.8px;` from the stylesheet and add `var el = document.querySelector('nav');`

Comment: That is the initial font size which is required.

Comment: Set it in on the nav container then

Comment: But,I want to maintain it in a separate CSS file only. When I console the queryselector it fetches the correct font but does not change it from the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

1. Create an array of items on the page with their corresponding min and max sizes
2. Have one function decide if it is increase or decrease (DRY)
3. loop over the array

NOTE: I moved the font-size of the nav to the nav container

NOTE: I have NOT tested this in IE8. It is not feasible to support anything lower than IE11

```js
var items = [{
  "el": "nav",
  "maxSize": 30,
  "minSize": 12.8
}, {
  "el": "#test",
  "maxSize": 50,
  "minSize": 20
}]
var incdec = function(dir) {
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    size(dir, item)
  });
};
var size = function(dir, item) {
  var el = document.querySelector(item.el);
  var max = item.maxSize;
  var min = item.minSize;
  console.log(dir, min,max)
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
  var fontSize = parseFloat(style);
  if (dir === 1 && fontSize <= max) {
    el.style.fontSize = (fontSize + 2) + 'px';
    console.log("incSize", el.tagName, el.style.fontSize)
  } else if (dir === -1 && fontSize >= min) {
    el.style.fontSize = (fontSize - 2) + 'px';
    console.log("decSize", el.tagName, el.style.fontSize)
  }
}
```

```css
/* Basic styling */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background: #001a33;
  font-size: 12.8px;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #91d5f3;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.submenu {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.submenu-select {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg py-0 " id="header-bar">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-dark navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="first">ITEM1<span
                                class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link " href="#">ITEM0</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link px-3" href="#">ITEM2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link " href="#">ITEM3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link px-3 " href="#">ITEM4</a>
        </li>
        <label for="submenu" class="submenu px-2">Submenu:</label>
        <select name="submenu" id="submenu" class="submenu-select">
          <option value="Option1">option1</option>
          <option value="Option2">option2</option>
        </select>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<button onclick="incdec(1)">INCREASE</button>
<button onclick="incdec(-1)">DECREASE</button>

<h1 id="test">FONT CHANGE</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you. But looking at OP version of JS and yours totally separate versions invloving `array` and `foreach` loop. so ideally its good to add information for other users. By all means i would say its a nice answer. I upvoted.